# Spring MongoRepository query adding _class field to queries

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a domain class called User. It uses an object of `MyUserId` as the `Id`

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Property
    @Id
    private MyUserId id;
    @Version
    private Integer version;

    private String firstName;
// Setters, getters 
}
```

The `MyUserId` class:

```
public class MyUserId implements Serializable{
    @Property
    private String userId;
    @Property
    private String sampleId;
// setters, getters
    }
```

Inside my Mongo, documents are getting stored as `{_id:{userId:....., sampleId:....}, <more fields here>}`

My userRepository is like this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, MyUserId> {
    @Query("{'_id': {$in: ?0}}")
    List<User> findByUserIds(Collection<MyUserId> userIds);
}
```

When I'm querying my userRepository, The query is being fired as:

```
{_id:  {$in: [ {_class:"com.sampleuser.MyUserId", userId:"....", sampleId:"...."}, {_class:"com.sampleuser.MyUserId", userId:"....", sampleId:"...."}]}}
```

It's obvious that it's adding the _class field while querying, but not while storing. Can someone throw some light at how to fix this? It's causing all my queries to fail.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There actually exists an issue when using `@Query` whith complex id types. I'd suggest to use a custom repository implementation until [DATAMONGO-1078](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1078) is resolved.

Within the custom implementation you could use `MongoTemplate` to execute the query somehow like this

```
@Override
public List<User> findByUserIds(Collection<MyUserId> userIds) {
    return template.find(query(where("id").in(userIds)), User.class);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it's an issue, I was getting there.